# C++ (console) Constructors and derived classes

Tags: c++, class, constructor, derived

Let's suppose I create a struct that has two variables.

```
struct mystruct{
public:
string name;
int age;};

class School :public mystruct{
private:
mystruct student;
bool status;
int major;}
```

In mystruct, if I created an overloaded constructor to assign my two variables values, but I only want to create obj through the class. How could that constructor ever come into play? Would I place it in the class to access the variables of mystruct?

Note: I know i did not put any constructors here, but I am wondering on this question before proceeding.

Ex. If I create a School obj, can I have a constructor set mystruct.name & mystruct.age automatically?? I don't want to create the mystruct obj outside the class School.

Comment: A school that both *has* a student (exactly one student, to be precise) and *is* a student?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but your design seems a little odd to me. It seems that  `mystruct` should really be named something like `Person`, and that makes the inheritance weird as a `School` is definitely not a `Person`. Perhaps is it was `class Student : public Person` it would make more sense, but then you would not need the `student` member.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in that `mystruct` is both a base class and a member of `School`. Not an error but a bit odd. Since your question is about derived classes I'll ignore the member variable.

You call the constructor for `mystruct` from the constructor for `School`. For example

```
struct mystruct{
public:
    mystruct(string n, int a) : name(n), age(a) {}
    string name;
    int age;
};

class School : public mystruct {
public:
    School(string name, int age, bool s, int m) : 
        mystruct(name, age), // call to the base class constructor
        status(s), major(m) {}
private:
    bool status;
    int major;
}
```

Your class design is very strange. A school is (presumably) a collection of students, but your design seems to only allow for a single student. That needs fixing before you go any further.

There's the technical issue (how to call a base class constructor) which I answered here. But don't let that make you think you've solved the *class design* issue which is actually a much bigger deal. Your program will never be right until you have a sensible design.

Comment: Hey thanks - that was what I was looking for .. I really thank you .....